# How to write Mongolian character use task

Tags: cyrillic, tasks

I have a problem. I write use tasks in `LaTeX`. But list is ABC of English.

How i write Mongolian Character that list.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mongolian]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[b5paper, margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{ {img/} }
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
  after-skip = -\parskip , % undo paragraph skip
  after-item-skip = -\parskip % undo paragraph skip
}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\section*{7 дугаар анги}
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task 9
\task 8
\task 1
\task 0
\end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\useg` instead of `\asbuk`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mongolian]{babel}

\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{ label = \useg*) }

\begin{document}

\section{дугаар анги}
\begin{tasks}(4)
  \task
  \task
  \task
  \task
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Баярлалаа. Их амархан байсан байна. Өмнө нь asbuk-аар нэг хэсэг болж байснаа сүүлд болохоо байсан юм.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Cyrillic equivalent to `\alph`. The Russian language module defines `\asbuk` for this.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,mongolian]{babel}

\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{ label = \asbuk*) }

\begin{document}

\section{дугаар анги}
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task 9
\task 8
\task 1
\task 0
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]